# Best practice for query to select a column twice

Tags: sql, database

I have a table called `concept-relation` that contains 3 columns

```
(relationID, firstConceptID, secondConceptID)
```

I have a table called `concept` contains 2 columns

```
(ID, name)
```

I want to get the name for the `firstConceptID` and `secondConceptID` when the `relationID  = 22`.

This is the query that I came up with.

```
select * from (
      select name as source from concept where concept.ID in (
      select firstConceptID from `concept-relation` where relationID = 22
       ) 
) as e,
(
      select name as des from concept where concept.ID in (
      select secondConceptID from `concept-relation` where relationID = 22
     )
)as e
```

It works well, but I want to know what is the best practice for carrying out such queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need a self-join to make it cleaner ***usually*** considered more of a best practice as it avoids the sub selects / "IN"s

```
SELECT C1.name, C2.name
FROM Concept C1
INNER JOIN concept_Relation CR 
  ON CR.FirstConceptID = C1.ID
INNER JOIN Concept C2 
  ON CR.SecondConceptID = C2.ID
WHERE CR.RelationID = 22
```